# Generating Multiplication problems Python

Tags: python

Hello so I'm trying to make a script that gives the user the options to generate 1-10 different multiplication problems for them to answer but I'm having issues I believe i'm not taking the right approach with this script if someone could help me out I'd appreciate it!

```
from random import randint


random_number1 = randint(0, 12)
random_number2 = randint(0, 12)

sum = random_number1 * random_number2

key = int(input('How many problems do you want to solve? '))

if key == 1:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )


elif key == 2:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )

elif key == 3:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )

elif key == 4:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )

elif key == 5:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )

elif key == 6:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )

elif key == 7:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )

elif key == 8:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )

elif key == 9:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )

elif key == 10:
    print(random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', sum )

else:
    print('Invalid Number')
```

Comment: thanks for asking your question. What is `sum` supposed to represent? Are you wanting the user to be able to type in an answer? Alternately, should the code show the correct answer?

Comment: How is your code not working?

Comment: E. Ducateme Thank you for your reply the sum part I was an idea I was tossing around so what I'm trying to do is ask a user how many problems they want generated lets say they say 6 so it generates  6 problems for them to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
from random import randint

questions = int(input('How many problems do you want to solve? '))

# Since we want to ask multiple questions, this is a good case for using
#     a for loop. Putting a number into the range() function will 
#     enable our for loop to repeat that number of times
for num in range(questions):

    # To ensure that we make new random numbers each time, we have to put 
    #     the following steps inside the for loop.
    random_number1 = randint(0, 12)
    random_number2 = randint(0, 12)
    answer = random_number1 * random_number2

    # Strings have a format method that allows us to create templates
    #     to allow us to input new values into the string every time 
    #     the for loop cycles.
    print("{} x {} = {}".format(r1, r2, answer))
```

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

How about the following code:

```
import random

upper_limit = 10
number_problems = int(input('How many problems do you want to solve? '))
for i in range(number_problems):
    x, y = random.randint(1,upper_limit), random.randint(1,upper_limit)
    true_ans = x*y
    print(x ,'x', y , '=' )
    ans = int(input('your answer:'))
    if ans == true_ans:
        print("correct!")
    else:
        print("incorrect! The answer is ", true_ans)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ray! That's exactly what I needed I've been trying to figure that out for hours now!

Comment: @Jake I am glad you like it! This is what I would do. Also, you can tune the difficulty level by changing the upper limit for the random number :D  ( I will leave the lower limit for you to implement :D)

Answer (score 1):

not sure of what you tried to do, but I guess you mean to generate diferent random number with every iteration (the number you ask for), so what about this?

```
from random import randint
MAX_PROBLEMS = 10

key = int(input('How many problems do you want to solve? '))

if key > 0 and key <= MAX_PROBLEMS:
    for i in range(key):
        random_number1 = randint(0, 12)
        random_number2 = randint(0, 12)
        print random_number1,'x',random_number2, '=', random_number1*random_number2
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a go at something like what you want. It introduces a few different features of python: `for` and `while` loops, `try` / `except` clauses, assertion errors.

Try it, play with it, study the code and make sure you understand each bit, and then come back and ask questions. Good luck!

```
from random import randint

while True:
    try:
        key = int(input('How many problems do you want to solve?'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid entry. Input an integer.')
        continue

for k in range(key):

    x, y = randint(0, 12), randint(0, 12)

    while True:
        try:
            i = int(input('What is {0} times {1}?'.format(x, y)))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid entry. Input an integer.')
            continue

    assert i == x*y, "Incorrect! The correct answer is {0}, while you input {1}".format(x*y, i)

print("Well done! You answered all questions correctly!")
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help!